# Outlook Graph API not receiving groups

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

What I am trying to achieve -
When I call message API, it returns the group address to which mail is sent, I want to get the members of the group, And for that I believe I need group Id, so I am using the groups API mentioned below `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups`

But this API returns an empty list to me.

Note: email I using is @outlook.com, not xyz.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft graph API doesn't support [personal accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) as you can see the below image. You should have a Work account to get the group details. You were able to get the [messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) because it supports personal accounts to read messages from your mailbox.

[image]